# Connecting PWM pulse out to another chip

Tags: integrated-circuit, circuit-design

I am working on a small hardware project where I am generating a PWM pulse of 5ms from an ARM chip pin that I provide as an input to a counter chip that counts these pulses. The input pin on the counter chip is pulled down with a resistor of 100k. Do I need to add any additional passive components to ensure robustness? I apologize if this is a basic question.

EDIT: The PWM out is from a general purpose I/O pin of this BLE [module](http://www.skylab.com.cn/uploadfile/Download/201508031149007345.pdf) and I am connecting it to a hardware counter chip to check if it is alive or not and reset otherwise. They will share the same power source (small battery). A small pulse shouldn't affect the Vcc but I wanted to make sure it doesn't drain too much current as to affect Vcc. Do I need to ensure any pin is in high impedance state?

Comment: Can you provide more details? What does your circuit layout look like? What are you trying to accomplish with this project? The more information you provide, the more we can help you.

Comment: Added some clarification in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming both chips use compatible logic levels, no, you shouldn't need any additional components.